# How to initialize class member outside the member initializer list

Tags: c++, initialization, member

I have a C++ class that takes a string (file path) in its constructor, loads that file into a JSON and then uses some of the JSON variables to initialize another member.

As the file needs to be loaded first, and the the JSON initialized (from stream), I cannot initialize `thing` in the member initializer list. Should I use another wrapper class for the JSON, use new...? How can I achieve this?

```
class Dummy
{
    std::string _configFilePath;
    json configJson;
    Thing thing;

    Dummy(std::string configFilePath = "../config.json") :
    _configFilePath(configFilePath)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(configFilePath);
        ifs >> configJson;
        thing(configJson["whatever"]); // thing can't be initialized here
    }
};
```

Note that `thing` is not default constructible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a helper function to do what the current constructor does:

```
class Dummy
{
    std::string _configFilePath;
    json configJson;
    Thing thing;

    Thing loader() {
        std::ifstream ifs(_configFilePath);
        ifs >> configJson;
        return Thing(configJson["whatever"]);
    }

    Dummy(std::string configFilePath = "../config.json") :
        _configFilePath(configFilePath), thing(loader())
    {
    }
};
```

This will construct `_configFilePath` and default construct `configJson`, then call `loader` to load the thing.  RVO should enable construction of `thing` directly in `loader`.

Comment: Thanks, that compiled!

Answer (score 2):

Is `Thing` both default constructable and move-assignable? If so:

```
class Dummy
{
    std::string _configFilePath;
    json configJson;
    Thing thing;

    Dummy(std::string configFilePath = "../config.json") :
    _configFilePath(configFilePath)
    {
        std::ifstream ifs(configFilePath);
        ifs >> configJson;
        thing = Thing(configJson["whatever"]);   // move-assign a new object
    }
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. It's not  default constructable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the combination of a delegating constructor and a helper function that loads the `json` object to properly initilize the objects.

```
class Dummy
{
    std::string _configFilePath;
    json _configJson;
    Thing _thing;

    // Use a delegating constructor
    Dummy(std::string configFilePath = "../config.json") :
       Dummy(configFilePath, getConfig(configFilePath) {}

    Dummy(std::string configFilePath, json configJson) :
       _configFilePath(configFilePath),
       _configJson(configJson),
       _thing(configJson["whatever"]) {}

    // Load and return the json object.
    static json getConfig(std::string configFilePath)
    {
       std::ifstream ifs(configFilePath);
       json configJson;
       ifs >> configJson;
       return configJson;
    }
};
```